# How create FAQ for users of SSRS report server?

Tags: user-interface, reporting-services, document

How can I provide an FAQ type document, so that the FAQ will be accessible on an SSRS report server?  There won't be any data in the FAQ; it will just have text descriptions of the data.  Note that this is different from the report descriptions which I've embedded in each report's Description property.

Comment: Why not just create a separate report with text boxes that you fill out with FAQ's?

Comment: @BJones: Thank you.  I considered doing just that, but I wondered if there might be a better way.  My proposed FAQ is likely to be quite lengthy.

Comment: I would think it's just as easy as any other solution. You could even do one big text box and just copy/paste everything you have. Just resize the text box so everything displays

Comment: @BJones: Thanks again.  I'm going to give it a try.  I think that I could have a series of "question" textboxes, with a brief question in each such textbox.  When clicked, each question textbox would toggle the visibility property of a corresponding "answer" textbox containing the answer.  This way the answers would be hidden initially, possibly making it easier for the user to find what they're looking for.  If that sounds right to you, you could repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could probably do this.

As I stated in comments earlier you could create multiple text boxes with corresponding answers on a separate report.

You could also paste everything in one text box and make it readable.

Another option which coincides with the first option and like you stated could allow for toggling visibility of the answers would be to change the visibility property of the answer to "Hide" and checking the "Display can be toggled by this report item":

[image][image: Visibility Properties]